# Extract addresses from fire pager messages using a regex

Tags: regex, parsing

I have a VB.NET program I run that receives fire pager messages (I am a volunteer), and one of the functions of the program is to try and extract addresses from the message. If I was lucky the messages would be coded with a prefix before them (e.g. `LOC`) then the address, however I am not lucky and the format changes all the time, so I need to try and come up with a regex that covers most formats of address.

All messages have the same format for the end, which is usually either a melways reference (`M` proceeded by page and grid reference) or some other map, so I have my end point `(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)` and I want the message to start before that point (I run right to left for this reason).

The start of the message varies, if I am lucky it is a corner address and has `CNR`, or a street number in which case I can use `(CNR|ASSEMBLE AT|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ )))` and in the  middle use `.*?`

So where I am confused though, is in my regex example below it is not working, I would like to try and have a priority in terms of try this first, then the next thing, then the next thing but I cant get this to work.

These are some example messages with addresses (I have changed the addresses to random streets).

```
ALERT F1234567 PKHM2 STRUC1 BURNING SMELL INSIDE HOUSE 19 THIS ROAD BVD SUBURB /NEAREST ST CR M 123 B8 (660846)

ALERT F1234567 PKHM2 STRUC1 HOUSE FULL OF SMOKE 7 EXAMPLE CT SUBURB /CROSSRD1 BVD //CROSSRD2 CCT M 123 K10 (653837)

ALERT F1234567 PKHM2 NOSTC1 CAR FIRE CNR EXAMPLE1 CL/EXAMPLE2 WAY SUBURB M 123 J6 (646853)

ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 FACTORY FIRE EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833)

ALERT F1234567 PAKU5 STRUC1 BBQ AREA ON FIRE EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 G7 (677948) 

ALERT F1234567 SFLD3 G&SC1 COLUMN OF SMOKE ISSUING EXAMPLE RD SUBURB SVC 1234 H3 (075622)
```

So when I use my regex down the very bottom, only the first three work, whilst the last three do not. What I was hoping I could have the regex do is:

- If the Street number, or `CNR` is there take the address (excluding the map reference) to the `CNR` or street number, e.g. in the first example this would be: `19 THIS ROAD BVD SUBURB /NEAREST ST CR`.
- If that is not there, but one of the other phrases is (e.g. `FIRE`) then take the address excluding that phrase, and the map reference. so the fire call `ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 FACTORY FIRE EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833)` would become `EXAMPLE RD SUBURB`.

The other thing I am curious about is can I have this as something that has three or more options, so take regex 1 if it exist, then if not take regex 2 if it exists, then if not take regex 3 if it exists.

So for example, if I have a call such as `ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 FACTORY FIRE 123 EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833)`, the first regex looks for the 123 (or CNR) and if found includes them in the returned regex, then if that does not exist it looks for `(FACTORY FIRE|GAS LEAK|EXAMPLE 1|EXAMPLE 2|EXAMPLE 3)` but does not include them in the returned regex, and then if that is not found it looks for `(STRUC[13]|INCIC[13])` and does not include that in the returned regex.

- So in example 1 of the above `ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 FACTORY FIRE 123 EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833)` returns `123 EXAMPLE RD SUBURB`.
- In example 2 of the above `ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 FACTORY FIRE EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833)` returns `EXAMPLE RD SUBURB`.
- In example 3 of the above `ALERT F1234567 PKHM1 STRUC1 EXAMPLE RD SUBURB M 123 J11 (686833) returns EXAMPLE RD SUBURB`.

Regex:

> `(?<=(\d HOUR[S])).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)|(CNR|ASSEMBLE AT|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)|(?<=(CAR SMOULDERING |SPREADING|WASHAWAY ON|FACTORY FIRE|CAR ACCIDENT - POSS PERSON TRAPPED|CAR FIRE|ENT|INPUT|RHS|LHS|RESULT OF ACCIDENT|GAS BOTTLE EXPLOSION|INPUT|VICINITY OF|OFF|OPPOSITE|SPARKING|INCIC1|INCIC3|STRUC1|STRUC3|G&SC1|G&SC3|ALARC1|ALARC3|NOSTC1|NOSTC3|RESCC1|RESCC3|HIARC1|HIARC3|CAR ACCIDENT - POSS PERSON TRAPPED|EXPLOSIONS HEARD|RESULT OF ACCIDENT|ENTRANCE|ENT|FIRE|LHS|RHS|POWER LINES ARCING AND SPARKING|SMOKE ISSUING FROM FAN|CAR FIRE|ALARM OPERATING|GAS LEAK|GAS PIPE|NOW OUT|ACCIDENT|SMOKING|ROOF|GAS|REQUIRED|FIRE|LOCKED IN CAR|SMOKE RISING|SINGLE CAR ACCIDENT|ACCIDENT|FIRE)).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)(?<=(LOC)).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)`

Comment: I agree with @JakeGould. This is not a job for regexes. Write the logic in code, and solve the problem step by step — that will be a lot easier.

Comment: It is an Australian system, and is entirely frustrating that it does not have address start points. I would like to avoid if/else logic just simply because if the logic changes I have to reprogram, whereas with regex i can just save the string in a file and change it as needed. I thought with regex you could do (Regex1)|(Regex2)|(Regex3) e.g. (CNR|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)|Regex2|Regex3?

Comment: This seems to work, although may not be the best solution: (CNR|(([\d]+/[\d]+)|([\d]+ / [\d]+)|([\d]+-[\d]+)|([\d]+ - [\d]+)|( [\d]+ ))).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)|(?<=FACTORY FIRE|FIRE|ISSUING).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)|(?<=STRUC[13]|INCIC[13]|ALARC[13]).*?(?=SV[NCSEWV]| M |SVVB)

Comment: Using one regular expression may be possible but it will be difficult to maintain as new variations are required. I would suggest a mix of regular expressions and code where each section performs a clearly defined operation and is easy to validate.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I did get it to work with one Regex, but I take your point that perhaps it might be better to mix both code and regular expressions and will look at incorporating that in future versions.